# Main Activity is not executing a class inside on create

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to execute CheckInternetConnection  class inside my main activity on create but when the oncreate is called the class is not getting launced however when i press back navigation button Main Activity successfully executes CheckInternetConnection :

Here's my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawer=findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        mDrawer.setTouchMode(ElasticDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_BEZEL);
        Context context=this.getApplicationContext();
        setupToolbar();
        setupMenu();
        search();
              new CheckInternetConnection(this).checkConnection();
                FragmentManager pr = getSupportFragmentManager();
                ProjectListFragment prjlist = (ProjectListFragment) 
                pr.findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
                if (prjlist == null) {
                    prjlist = new ProjectListFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                            android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    pr.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.id_main_frame, prjlist).commit();
        }




public void onBackPressed() {
        int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);//This intent will refresh mainactivity on back press
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            //additional code
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            finish();
        }


    }
```

This class will basically check for internet connection and display dialog if connection is not present.

```
public class CheckInternetConnection {

    Context ctx;

    public CheckInternetConnection(Context context){
        ctx=context;
    }

    public void checkConnection(){

        if(!isInternetConnected()) {

            final FancyAlertDialog.Builder alert = new FancyAlertDialog.Builder(ctx)
                    .setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                    .setimageResource(R.drawable.internetconnection)
                    .setTextTitle("No Internet")
                    .setTextSubTitle("Cannot connect to server")
                    .setBody(R.string.noconnection)
                    .setPositiveButtonText("Connect Now")
                    .setNegativeButtonText("Go Offline")
                    .setOnNegativeClicked(new FancyAlertDialog.OnNegativeClicked() {
                        @Override
                        public void OnClick(View view, Dialog dialog) {
                            Intent in=new Intent(ctx,MainActivity.class);
                            in.putExtra("offline","offline");
                            ctx.startActivity(in);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                    .setOnPositiveClicked(new FancyAlertDialog.OnPositiveClicked() {
                        @Override
                        public void OnClick(View view, Dialog dialog) {

                            if(isInternetConnected()){
                                Intent in=new Intent(ctx,MainActivity.class);
                                ctx.startActivity(in);
                                dialog.dismiss();

                            }else {

                                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                ctx.startActivity(dialogIntent);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setBodyGravity(FancyAlertDialog.TextGravity.CENTER)
                    .setTitleGravity(FancyAlertDialog.TextGravity.CENTER)
                    .setSubtitleGravity(FancyAlertDialog.TextGravity.CENTER)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .build();
            alert.show();
        }
    }

    public boolean isInternetConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();

    }
}
```

Comment: What class ? And what is `new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class)`? Explain your problem its pretty much unclear right now .

Comment: Class i'm talking about is CheckInternetConnection 
new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class) is for refreshing the activity on back press

Comment: Try by creating the object first then call the method after fragment transaction; see if that helps.

Comment: Also you may try to call the method inside onStart.

Comment: I tried calling it in onstart but it doesn't work when activity is launched first time however when i press the back button and refresh the activity method is successfully launched.

Comment: Do not use the back button to refresh the app. It is counter-intuitive and against Google's guidelines ( https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal ) to have a different behaviour to back button. It breaks user experience and their expectation. Add your log file to the question to better illustrate the problem you're facing. Why are you using another class to check for internet Android provides such features already, like https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring . Also see previously asked questions on SO.